# Including result of string joining command in command line tool call powershell 5.0

Tags: powershell, pdftk

I would like to include the result of a string concatenation command as part of a call using the `pdftk` command line tool. Here's what I tried:

```
$items_to_merge = '"' + $($(get-childitem *.pdf).name -join '" "') + '"'

echo $items_to_merge
pdftk $items_to_merge cat output test.pdf
```

The individual pdf file names themselves include spaces, so that's why I'm wrapping every file name with double quotes.

However it turns out that when I run this command I get `pdftk` errors as follows:

> Error: Unable to find file

I'm a bit surprised because enumerating the files by hand and wrapping with double quotes has always worked. Why does it fail when I do it programmatically?

Comment: You might have to backslash the doublequotes.  pdftk can't use wildcards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situation `invoke-expression` is your friend:

```
$items_to_merge = '"' + $($(get-childitem *.pdf).name -join '" "') + '"'
echo $items_to_merge
invoke-expression "pdftk $items_to_merge cat output test.pdf"
```

Comment: Use the invocation operator instead: `& "pdftk $items_to_merge cat output test.pdf"`

Comment: What's wrong with `invoke-expression`?

Comment: Plenty of reasons: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/. this is just one of many reasons/articles.

Comment: I see. Good to know thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Going simpler works ok in Windows Sandbox, with an array of strings with or without extra double quotes.  I printed a webpage to pdf to make a sample pdf.

```
$items_to_merge = (get-childitem *.pdf).name

$items_to_merge
pdftk $items_to_merge cat output test.pdf
```

Or with a wildcard:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output test.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Let PowerShell do the quoting of the file names. By using `@` instead of `$` in front of the variable name, PowerShell expands the array into individual arguments (aka [array splatting)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2#splatting-with-arrays) which will be quoted if necessary.

```
$items_to_merge = (get-childitem *.pdf).name
pdftk @items_to_merge cat output test.pdf
```

As commenter [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) pointed out, splatting is not even necessary. This also works:

```
$items_to_merge = (get-childitem *.pdf).name
pdftk $items_to_merge cat output test.pdf
```

Apparently PowerShell implicitly splats an array argument when passed to a **native command**.

Personally I still prefer explicit splatting as it consistently works with both native and PowerShell commands.

Comment: Even `$items_to_merge` works in this case.

Comment: @js2010 Nice one, learnt something new!